# transpose or translate Expression Linq

Tags: linq

I have viewmodel (say memberviewmodel) and ef model (say member). how do i translate from

```
> GetByProperty(Expression<Func<MemberViewModel, bool>> whereCondition)
```

to

```
> GetByProperty(Expression<Func<Member, bool>> whereCondition)
```

any ideas?

My service exposes the method GetByProperty(Expression> whereCondition) but then within the service, it calls the business object which exposes a method GetByProperty(Expression> whereCondition).

Comment: What do you mean translate? do you want to call getsingle?

Comment: how do i communicate between those two method? you cannot use the whereCondition just passing it into the second method, can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `Expression<Func<MemberViewModel, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<Member, bool>>` you'll need to extend the [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx) class. I've assumed `MemberViewModel` contains only fields and properties. `Member` of course needs to implement the same set of fields and properties. In this case the following should work:

```
public class ParameterModifier<TSrc, TDest> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    ParameterExpression parameter;

    public ParameterModifier()
    {
        parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDest), "member");
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type == typeof(TSrc))
        {
            return parameter;
        }
        else
            return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression.Type == typeof(TSrc))
        {
            return Expression.PropertyOrField(Visit(node.Expression), node.Member.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        if (node.Parameters.Any(p => p.Type == typeof(TSrc)))
        {
            return Expression.Lambda(Visit(node.Body), node.Parameters.Select(p => p.Type == typeof(TSrc) ? parameter : p));
        }
        else
        {
            return base.VisitLambda<T>(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Before passing the predicate to the second method you can now convert it using the class above:

```
IEnumerable<MemberViewModel> GetByProperty(Expression<Func<MemberViewModel, bool>> whereCondition)
{
    var converter = new ParameterModifier<MemberViewModel, Member>();
    var convertedExpression = converter.Visit(original) as Expression<Func<Member, bool>>;
    IEnumerable<Member> members = GetByProperty(convertedExpression);
    return members.Select(new MemberViewModel(member));
}
```